Record triggered flow-deletion trigger
I want to create a flow where when an account gets deleted so does the related contacts and finally it updates the account name field on related opportunities with Unknown. How to do it?
I have tried creating one and it deletes both the contacts and opportunities.
When I put Account Id equals to Unknown in update records element, it gives me an error.Could someone please help me with this?

Remember, we can't read your mind, see your screen, or log into your org. You need to [edit] your question to show us what you've tried. Including the full text of the error message(s) you're seeing is also important (it's hard to help diagnose/fix an error if we don't know what it is).


I have tried creating one and it deletes both the contacts and opportunities.

When you delete an account, the contacts, opportunities, cases, and activities are also deleted automatically. This is standard Salesforce functionality.

When I put Account Id equals to Unknown in update records element, it gives me an error.

Salesforce ID values are always 15-character case-sensitive or 18-character case-insensitive (as in Excel case-sensitivity). You'd have to use a Get Records element to find an account named Unknown if you wanted to have Salesforce show the name Unknown.
However, this is probably not a great idea. If a user recovers the account from the recycle bin, for example, the related contacts and opportunities won't be restored. This may also affect reports, dashboards, and other places. I wouldn't recommend doing this.
